# Error in Connecting the MongoDB server with Node app MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb, macos, express, mongodb-compass

I am working on a MERN project and Earlier my mongo server was working fine, but now that I have restarted my app it is giving me error i.e is
`

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/Development/MERN PROJECT/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:824:32)
    at /Users/vaibhav/Desktop/Development/MERN PROJECT/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:381:10
    at /Users/vaibhav/Desktop/Development/MERN PROJECT/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/Development/MERN PROJECT/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/Development/MERN PROJECT/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1234:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/Development/MERN PROJECT/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:380:20)
    at connectDataBase (/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/Development/MERN PROJECT/backend/config/dataBase.js:7:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/Development/MERN PROJECT/backend/server.js:17:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

`My confige.env file looks like this`

```
PORT = 4000
DB_URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/Ecommerce"

JWT_SECRET=JBRON098SROINRIOUHOHSDOKFN948HIFRCN
JWT_EXPIRE=5d

COOKIE_EXPIRE = 5
```

`My app.js file looks like this`

```
const app = require('./app')

const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const connectDataBase = require("./config/dataBase")

//Handling uncaught exception
process.on("uncaughtException", (err) => {
    console.log(`Error: , ${err.message}`);
    console.log(`Shutting down server due to unhandled promise rejection`);
    process.exit(1);
})

//config file
dotenv.config({path:"backend/config/config.env"});

//Calling the function to connect the database
connectDataBase();

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, ()=>{
    console.log(`The server has started at http://localhost/${process.env.PORT}`);
})
```

I have also tried connecting with compass but it is still not working. I used a MacBook air m2 with macOS Ventura 13.0.1

I wanted to connect to the server using the app only but it is giving me the error

`

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/Development/MERN PROJECT/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:824:32)
    at /Users/vaibhav/Desktop/Development/MERN PROJECT/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:381:10
    at /Users/vaibhav/Desktop/Development/MERN PROJECT/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/Development/MERN PROJECT/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/Development/MERN PROJECT/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1234:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/Development/MERN PROJECT/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:380:20)
    at connectDataBase (/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/Development/MERN PROJECT/backend/config/dataBase.js:7:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/Development/MERN PROJECT/backend/server.js:17:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

`

Comment: Is `mongod` running?

Comment: install `mongosh`, run `mongosh` or `mongosh --host localhost Ecommerce`, check your connection is ready?

Comment: yes i first type mongod on terminal and then I run my app